# iOS streaming camera feed to another device

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, streaming, wifi

Has anyone tried to streaming the camera feed of one iOS device to another device?  So for example a iPhone camera feed to a iPad 1.  I guess you could keep taking pictures and sending over Bluetooth but that would probably work very badly.

The ideal solution would be to stream video and location over to one device via wifi and be able to send data back.

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution.  Please post your own answer here if you find it elsewhere.  I'll do the same.

Comment: Slso refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205942/ios-develop-iphone-app-to-stream-camera-video-to-a-computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this project](https://github.com/nicnocquee/iPad-iPhone-Photo-Booth--iPhone-as-Wireless-Cam-for-iPad-) I hope this helps.

Comment: thats not swift.