# iOS - Develop iPhone app to stream camera video to a computer?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, stream

I'm looking for a way to create an app that will allow captured camera video to be streamed on a computer. For example, one person could be walking an iPhone around a room and another person could have that video streamed on their computer. Something kind of like a one-way Facetime except the receiver is on a computer. Also, I can't just use an existing app as later I would like to change the program to do some computer vision processing on the incoming data.

At the moment, I've found that AV Foundation should be the correct option for the video capture ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504992/iphone-video-camera-streaming)). However, I'm having difficulty finding the method by which I can actually stream this data. In particular, searching for how to create the apps on the iPhone frequently results in existing apps that do the task, but not how to create the app.

Can anyone give me a pointer to the information on how to stream the video capture from the iPhone? Thank you much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "Wowza media Server" for Streaming purpose
For wowza media server doenload :

[Wowza Download](http://www.wowza.com/pricing/installer)

After installing wowza Now you need to set up live setting in wowza for that purpose you need:

[Setting Up Live Application](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36)

For iOS side there is library is useful for video streaming using RTMP connection
You can get Library at

[RTMP library for Streaming](http://blog.themidnightcoders.com/index.php/2011/06/29/rtmp-communication-library-for-ios-is-available/)

Library example

[RTMP library for Streaming example](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos)

In this good example of Streaming from iOS side

Answer (score 0):

I had success with [ANGL lib](http://angl.tv/lib/) and Wowza media server. It gives smooths RTMP stream.